# How to replace attribute name in an html file while parsing it with lxml?

Tags: html, parsing, replace, lxml

I have an xml-file, where I need to replace values of the class attributes, depending on the dfn-text of each p-element.So, I have an html-file of this kind:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p class ='person'><dfn>New-York</dfn>
    <p class = 'place'><dfn>John Doe</dfn>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to parse this document and replace all values of class attributes with correct ones. In order to define if dfn-text is a place or person I have already a set of conditions in my script. So, I want to get the same html-file as output but with correct classes:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p class ='**place**'><dfn>New-York</dfn>
    <p class = '**person**'><dfn>John Doe</dfn>
  </body>
</html>
```

So far I tried to achieve it looking for the dfn's ancestor p and its attribute 'class', and then trying to replace it with replace() function, but it doesn't really work:

```
filename = open('file.html', 'r+')
tree = etree.parse(filename)

def f1():
  for dfn in tree.getiterator('dfn'):
    def_text = dfn.text
    if def_text == 'New York'  #a list of conditions in my real script, New York is an example only):

      class1 = ''.join(dfn.xpath('ancestor::p//@class') 

      filename.write(class1.replace('person', 'place'))
```

All I get is the same file, but with a line 'place' appended a the end...

Comment: _“All I get is the same file, but with a line 'place' appended a the end...”_ – well of course that’s all you get, because you are not really manipulating the XML anywhere – all you are doing is writing something into a text file opened in `r+` mode, so how do you expect the outcome to be anything else …?

Comment: Oh you are so helpful with your minus to my question and a sarcastic comment! I can see already that it does not work. I will hope for some better persons who can answer something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [lxml with xslt](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt-result-objects) to transform your html, like:

```
from lxml import etree

h = '''<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p class ='person'><dfn>New-York</dfn></p>
    <p class = 'place'><dfn>John Doe</dfn></p>
  </body>
</html>'''
doc = etree.fromstring(h, etree.HTMLParser())

xsl = '''<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:variable name="original-class" select="string(@class)" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:if test="dfn[text()='New-York']">
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('**', $original-class, '**')"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>'''
xslt_root = etree.XML(xsl)
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)
result_tree = transform(doc)
print result_treeoutput:
```

output:

```
$ python x.py 
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
  <body>
    <p class="**person**"><dfn>New-York</dfn></p>
    <p class="place"><dfn>John Doe</dfn></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This really looks like what I need)) BUT, I still have a little problem: this code applies changes to the whole document, all the classes become "person" or "place", depending on what I indicate in the template after concat. I need them to be changed depending on the contents of the dfn. If 'dfn-text' is a person, change its ancestor's class to 'person'. Is it possible to apply the template to only one p-tag, the ancestor of the 'dfn' in question?

Comment: I tried something like this:
 `for dfn in htree.getiterator('dfn'):
       def_text = dfn.text
       if def_text == 'New_york':
        xslt_root = etree.XML(xsl)
        transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)       
        p = dfn.xpath('ancestor::p')
        result_tree = transform(p)`

I know that transform(p) does not work, but I try to show the idea -  to apply the transformation to only one p, the ancestor of the given dfn.

Comment: answer updated, xslt is really the way to go, try to match the tag you want to apply the transformation on using something like `<xsl:if test="p[text()='New-York']">`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I finally used another way to solve it, but I think that I will probably use your idea about templates for dealing with <style> change in the resulting html-file... I need just to replace the current contents of the style tag with some other contents...